# How to run the same test on multiple url in playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I want to run the same test for some urls (1000+) and I want to be the quickest as possible.
I loop the test for each url, but when the number of urls exceeds 10, it will cause a timeout error.
I guess this may be because each test is ran sequentially, do we have a way to run test in parallel?

```
const queries = getQueries();

for (let i=0; i < queries.length; i++){
    test.describe('LinkBroken'+ i.toString(), () => {
        test(queries[i].split('\t')[2], async ({ page }, testInfo) => {

            const url = getUrl(queries[i])
            await page.goto(url);
        
            const locators = page.locator('#b_content').locator('a:visible');
            const locator_count = await locators.count()
        
            for (let i=0; i <locator_count; i++){
                const link = locators.nth(i);
                await link.highlight();
                await link.click({trial:true});
            }
        });
    })
}
```

I tried to set playwright config as below, but it still doesn't work with `fullyParallel: true` and `workers: 10`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the playwright documentation you should add this line before test logic.

```
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'parallel' });
```

More information [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#parallelize-tests-in-a-single-file)

Also you may need to extend your timeout in `playwright.config.ts` file due to default limit for one test is 30sec.